# How to set environment setting?

Tags: byteman

https://downloads.jboss.org/byteman/4.0.20/byteman-programmers-guide.html#environment-settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ru0t.png)
how to set "org.jboss.byteman.compileToBytecode" property?
this document doesn't give an example.

I try to set environment proproty as follow:

export org.jboss.byteman.dump.generated.classes=1

but get an issue:
-bash: export: `org.jboss.byteman.dump.generated.classes=1': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 1):

This is a JVM property. You can set it this way:

```bash
java -Dorg.jboss.byteman.dump.generated.classes=1 -javaagent:$BYTEMAN_HOME/lib/byteman.jar=script:appmain.btm AppMain foo bar baz
```